mysqldump fails with max_allowed_packet set to highest possible value
I'm trying to take a mysqldump of a database with the following options:
mysqldump --single-transaction --set-gtid-purged=OFF -uuser -ppassword -t -q --compact dbname -hdb_host > data.sql

However I get the following error:
mysqldump: Error 2020: Got packet bigger than **max_allowed_packet** bytes when dumping table `tablename` at row: 8

I am receiving this error despite modifying max_allowed_packet variable to highest possible value of 1073741824.

Have you tried repairing that table?

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE.

I think that LONGTEXT and LONGBLOB have unwritten limitations.
